# SQL Server Msg 2108

Tags: sql-server

I created and altered a trigger and everything worked well, but when I started the SQL Server Management Studio later on, the following error appeared:

> Msg 2108, Level 15, State 1, Procedure store_110, Line 43
>   Cannot create trigger on 'IT_ServerDB.dbo.Users' as the target is not in the current database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot create trigger on 'IT_ServerDB.dbo.Users' as the target is not in the current database.

It seems ,you are using three part naming like below

> 'IT_ServerDB.dbo.Users

use two part naming

```
use IT_ServerDB
go

create trigger triggername
on
and rest of syntax
```

Comment: I tried what you said and this time the following error appeared:          Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure store_110, Line 37
The object 'dbo.Users' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

Comment: you have to be in the database,on which you need to create trigger

Comment: what does it mean to be in the database?

Comment: `use databasename' means you are in that database

Comment: It's working. Thank you! But last time it worked without the need to type the code u just mentioned. It would be helpful for me to understand why. Could you say womething about that?

Comment: i am not sure ,what was the issue last time

Comment: There was no issue. That's why I can't figure out why is this time the USE command required but last time no.

Comment: @cool which database is current is part of the state of the DB session you are using. In Management Studio there is a drop down in the toolbar to select the current database, if you `use theDatabase` in the session you'll see the selected value update.